# Declaring delegate

Tags: objective-c, pointers, delegates

Just realized that the delegates I am declaring are not declared with pointer type.

so instead of this

```
id <AddViewControllerDelegate> *delegate;
```

I have this

```
id <AddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Why the last way is correct? Since `self` is pointer(I guess) then why delegate is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'id' is already a pointer type. It's just hidden behind the typedef.

```
typedef id          (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...); 
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

Comment: Where are those header files located?

Answer (score 0):

id is actually a pointer to an object.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with a pointer to a pointer. The compiler doesn't dislike them. They're perfectly valid, just not the same thing as a pointer to an object.